# need help converting this code to new Mongo Java driver

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am converting an old application from mongo driver v1 to the latest version of mongo java driver

currently I am using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.11</version>
</dependency>
```

The code I am facing issues is:

```
    @Override
    public String getSubTypeName(String flowerId, Integer subTypeId) {
        DBCollection collection = mongoTemplate.getCollection("flowers");
        
        QueryBuilder query = new QueryBuilder();
        query.and("configType").is("FLOWER_SUB_TYPE")
             .and("parentConfig").is(flowerId)
             .and("configKey").is(subTypeId)
             .or(
                     QueryBuilder.start("isDeleted").is(false).get(),
                     QueryBuilder.start("isDeleted").exists(false).get()
        );
    
        DBObject flowerName = collection.findOne(query.get());
        if(flowerName ==null || !flowerName.containsField("value"))
            return "empty";
        else return  (String) flowerName.get("value);
    }
```

The code will not compile in the new version of mongo-java-driver...
I understand that I need to change:

DBCollection  to  MongoCollection
DBObject      to  Document
findOne to collection.find().first()

I need help with the QueryBuilder object ,
how to achieve the "and" "or" operator uysing the new driver

Answer (score 2):

I think it's better to use MongoTemplate if you are upgrading things now. You can use `Query` from `import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;` to build query and `Criteria` from `import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;`.

here is a snippet you can checkout and your code can be something like that (not exactly i guess) :

```java
        Query query = new Query();
        Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("configType").is("configType")
                .and("parentConfig").is(flowerId)
                .and("configKey").is(subTypeId)
                .orOperator(Criteria.where("isDeleted").is(false)
                        .and("isDeleted").exists(false));
        query.addCriteria(criteria);

        BasicDBObject result = mongoTemplate.findOne(query,BasicDBObject.class,"flowers");
```

Comment: Thank you, that is different and will require so many code changes because there is tons of collection.find calls. I rather just use collection.find